# SQLAlchemy association table with soft delete

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to configure my SQLAlchemy models to use an association table for a relationship. The issue I have is that the association table has a column "removed". I can't find a way to tell SQLAlchemy **not** to return associated objects if the relationship has been removed (soft deleted).

Here is an example:

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    b_list = relationship("B", secondary=lambda: association_table, backref="a_list")

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = "b"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

association_table = Table(
    "a_b_association",
    metadata,
    Column("a_id", Integer, ForeignKey(A.id), primary_key=True),
    Column("b_id", Integer, ForeignKey(B.id), primary_key=True),
    Column("removed", Integer)
)
```

The example above will always return the relationship. I need to change the relationship to only return when "removed==0".

Thanks for any help with this.

I know the SQL query I want SQLAlchemy to make is:

```
SELECT A.id, B.id
FROM A
INNER JOIN a_b_association ON A.id=a_b_association.a_id
INNER JOIN B ON B.id=a_b_association.b_id
WHERE a_b_association.removed=0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `primaryjoin` and `secondaryjoin` property of relationship obj and then add the condition to filter only non-deleted row.

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    b_list = relationship(
        "B", 
        secondary=association_table,
        primaryjoin=(association_table.c.a_id == id and association_table.removed == 0)
        backref="a_list"
    )
```

For ref, you can read more in [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html#self-referential-many-to-many-relationship).

Comment: Thank you! I've been stuck on this for hours now. I just got it working using the `secondaryjoin` parameter. It looks like there are multiple ways to do it. This currently works for my example:

    `b_list = relationship("B", secondary=lambda: association_table, secondaryjoin="and(association_table.c.a_id==B.id, association_table.c.removed == 0)", backref="a_list")`

Comment: Yup, primaryjoin is to tell the way you join left table with assoc table and secondaryjoin is to tell the way you join right table with assoc table. Thank you for accept the answer :D